# IEEE-754 floating point computations, equality and narrowing

Tags: c++, floating-point, undefined-behavior, ieee-754

In the following code, the functions foo1,foo2 and foo3 are intended to be equivalent. However when run foo3 does not terminate from the loop, is there a reason why this is the case?

```
template <typename T>
T foo1()
{
   T x = T(1);
   T y = T(0);
   for (;;)
   {
      if (x == y) break;
      y = x;
      ++x;
   }
   return x;
}

template <typename T>
T foo2()
{
   T x = T(0);
   for (;;)
   {
      T y = x + T(1);
      if (!(x != y)) break;
      ++x;
   }
   return x;
}

template <typename T>
T foo3()
{
   T x = T(0);
   while (x != (x + T(1))) ++x;
   return x;
}

int main()
{
   printf("1 float:  %20.5f\n", foo1<float>());
   printf("2 float:  %20.5f\n", foo2<float>());
   printf("3 float:  %20.5f\n", foo3<float>());
   return 0;
}
```

Note: This was compiled using VS2010 with /fp precise in release mode. Not sure how GCC etc would treat this code, any information would be great.  Could this be an issue where in foo3, the x and x+1 values become NaN somehow?

Comment: Interesting issue. All three functions terminate as expected on gcc 4.2.1. I'm tempted to call it a bug in VS.

Comment: Hmm.  Smells like an overeager optimization (i.e., a compiler bug) to me.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Hangs for me under a debug build in VS2010

Comment: Works fine with GCC 4.4.3 on x86-64. Tested with "-O2", "-O2 -ffast-math", and "-O3 -ffast-math". All work fine and print the same result (16777216.00000)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I'm beginning to think the same thing, don't have access to gcc or clang atm, but will try it shortly.

Comment: If you compare the disassembly of the hanging version to the semantically equivalent `T y = x + T(1); while(x != y) ++x;` (which works) they look identical (at least, the important bits like the load and compare).  May take a more experienced eye to figure out, but I'm still looking into it...

Comment: @janneb: Thanks for confirming that!!! :)

Comment: @Ed S.: It get a little more tricky, when precision/strict/fast options are used. I wonder if msvc injects code that changes the floating point control world (FLDCW) depending on the mode its compiling with.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, I take it back about the bug.  For C at least (I don't know C++ that well), it's permissible for the compiler to use extra precision when evaluating expressions (assuming no assignment to local variables or explicit conversions).  I *think* (but need to check) that this applies to the `x + T(1)` in the 3rd example.  So my guess is that the sum and comparison there are being performed using the `double` type, so the comparison is always true, but after `x` hits `2**24` it doesn't budge any further.  Will write a properly researched answer later if no-one else gets there.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Seems like a reasonable conclusion, however wouldn't the bit pattern then be NaN for 32-bit float? If thats the case then if the computation is done using double or even extended 80-bit precision that can definetly result in a NaN when converted done to 32-bit float, once that's the case then nothing can ever match 'true' to a NaN hence the loop never exists?

Comment: NaNs shouldn't enter the picture;  any implicit conversions are going to via value, not bit pattern.

Comment: Also, per IEEE 754, a narrowing conversion shall result in +-inf if the value exceeds the range. Try e.g. "float x = DBL_MAX;".

Comment: @GellyRistor: VS uses the FLD instruction to load the values, which iirc promotes it to an 80 bit precision value.

Comment: BTW, the relevant passage from C99 (presumably there's something similar for C++) is in section 6.3.1.8, paragraph 2: "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be
represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby."  So while the behaviour is surprising and annoying, it's not a compiler bug.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens is most likely the following. On the x86 arch, intermediate calculations can be done with 80 bits of precision (long double is the corresponding C/C++ type). The compiler uses all 80 bits for the (+1) operation and for the (!=) operation, but truncates the results before storage.

So what your compiler really does is this:

```
while ((long double)(x) != ((long double)(x) + (long double)(1))) {
  x = (float)((long double)(x) + (long double)(1));
}
```

This is absolutely non-IEEE-conforming and causes endless headaches for everyone, but this is the default for MSVC. Use `/fp:strict` compiler flag to disable this behaviour.

This is my recollection of the problem from about 10 years ago so please forgive me if this is somehow not entirely correct. [See this for the official Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx).

**EDIT** I was very surprised to learn that g++ by default exhibits exactly the same behaviour (on i386 linux, but not with e.g. -mfpmath=sse).

Comment: +1.  Just using `double` rather than `long double` would be enough to cause problems here, but IIRC MS still likes to use the x87 FPU even for 64-bit builds, so `long double` seems more likely.

Comment: Great knowledgeable answer but I notice that on VS2008 even with `/fp:strict` foo3() still doesn't terminate?

Comment: @acraig5075: Agreed;  I don't see how `/fp:strict` could help here.  For `/fp:precise`, Microsoft's docs even specify that "Expression evaluation will follow the C99 FLT_EVAL_METHOD=2", confirming that intermediate values are computed to long double type.  For `/fp:strict`, the documentation doesn't say, but I don't see any reason to assume a `FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0` - like behaviour there.

Comment: @acraig5075: strangely, g++ does it too on x86/x87 32-bit arch. So this is probably a common x87 behaviour.